# Grammar Usage in context

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> 1. There is no scope to feel satisfaction given the feeble recovery track record
> 2. Given the generous policy support afforded to delinquent borrowers historically

Is 'given' grammatically perfect here?? To me for the first one in giving sholud be used instead of given and  for the second one 'giving' should be there in place of 'given'.

Comment: Your second example sentence is not a full sentence.  However "given" works fine in both examples.  "Giving" would be incorrect.  I am not posting this as an answer because I don't know how to explain why it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> ... given the feeble recovery track record

this is constructed as a participle phrase, and acts as an adverbial within the complete sentence.  **given** is a past/passive participle: it means that we have been given this information to take into account.

If you were to replace it by the present/active participle **giving**, it would mean that we are giving the information to somebody else... who else, though?

You could replace it by the active participle for a different verb, for example **considering**, to indicate that we are considering this information:

> ...considering the feeble recovery track record

**given** appears in some dictionaries as a preposition (which can also be used to form an adverbial phrase), but this doesn't work in all circumstances:

> he is doing pretty well, given that he is nearly 70.

a that-clause can follow a participle, but cannot follow a preposition.

Note that the latin word for something that is given is **datum**... well, that's the singular, but the plural is **data**, which we all associate with information.